# How to convert into dd-mmm-yyyy format to dd-mm-yyyy format in swing(core java)?

Tags: java, date

To convert `dd-mmm-yyyy` to `dd-mm-yyyy` format.

```java
String dateofbirth = ((JTextField) dobcalender.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();//date from jcalender

SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

tried these codes :

```java
System.out.println(myFormat.format(myFormat.parse(dateofbirth)));
myFormat.format(myFormat.parse(dateofbirth));
```

showing error parseexception

Comment: What is the exact value of `dateofbirth`? Note that `MM` is not the same as `mm`.

Comment: Sir value of date of birth is 24 Feb 2019

Comment: Can you show us the value contained by the String dateofbirth in your code ?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the format    **"24 Feb 2019"**

```
 SimpleDateFormat from=new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
 SimpleDateFormat to=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
 Date frm=from.parse("24 Feb 2019");
 System.out.println(frm);//Sun Feb 24 00:00:00 IST 2019
 System.out.println(to.format(frm));//24-02-2019
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to parse the `String` to `Date` object. Then you need to convert the `Date` object to a new formatted `String`. Here is the sample code:

```
String dateofbirth = "09-10-2010"; //date from jcalender
SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
// converting to Date object
Date date = myFormat.parse(dateofbirth);

SimpleDateFormat myFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
// converting Date object to new format
String formattedDate = myFormat1.format(date);
System.out.println(formattedDate); // prints: 09-Oct-2010
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Before Java8 , No thread safe , has to import multiple packages(util, text), throws checked Exception(ParseException)
    System.out.println(oldDate);    //21 Jul 2019
    SimpleDateFormat oldPattern = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat newPattern = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    try {
        Date date = oldPattern.parse(oldDate);
        String newDate = newPattern.format(date);
        System.out.println(newDate);   //21-07-2019
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // Exception handling message/mechanism/logging as per company standard
    }

    // In Java8, Thread Safe, Immutable, throws unchecked Exception(DateTimeParseException)

    DateTimeFormatter oldPattern8 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM-yyyy");
    DateTimeFormatter newPattern8 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");

    LocalDate datetime = LocalDate.parse(oldDate, oldPattern8);
    String output = datetime.format(newPattern8);

    System.out.println(output);  //21-07-2019
```